# Grails Integration test for a query having to_date?

Tags: oracle, grails, h2

Grails in memory H2 DB is not supporting to_date function..
so the suggestion I got by going through the forums is  using 'EXTRACT' function.
 But not sure how to replace the following to_Date with Extract.

to_date(currentDate,YYYY_MM_DD HH:MM.ss)..

Extract -?

Comment: Here's the documentation... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Use the built-in function [`parsedatetime(dateAsString, formatString)`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#parsedatetime)
- Create a [user defined function](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions)